# How to observe exception handling in LLVM-IR generated from Rust

Tags: rust, llvm-ir

What would be the most comprehensive example of a simple Rust application that would generate exception handling when transformed into LLVM-IR?

Specifically, I'm trying to observe how Rust generates/manages invokes, landing pads and unwinds. Something akin to:

```
invoke void@maythrow()
   to label %try.cont
   unwind label %dispatch.a
dispatch.a:
%cpA=catchpad[%rtti.A* @A.Type]
   to label %handle.a
   unwind label %dispatch.b

handle.a:
   invoke void@handleA()
      to label %catchret.a
      unwind label %catchend
catchret.a:
   catchret %cpA to label %exit

dispatch.b:
%cpB=catchpad[%rtti.B* @B.Type]
   to label %handle.b
   unwind label %dispatch.b
handle.b:
   invoke void@handleB()
      to label %catchret.b
      unwind label %catchend
catchret.b:
   catchret %cpB to label %exit
```

I'd like to avoid looking into Rust's source code and that is why I'm asking for such an example.

EDIT:
I expect that Rust would depend on these instructions because of the following articles: [1](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/10/30/dont-panic/), [2](https://youtu.be/9TlR9hNZbck?t=1848) and of the no-landing-pads option in the -Z flag.

EDIT: A [quick search](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=landingpad&type=Code) through Rust source code also indicates that it is somehow generated.

Comment: Do you know about the [Rust Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/)? (there is a LLVM IR to get the compiler to generate IR instead of a binary)

Comment: Yes. And I can generate LLVM-IR with the --emit=llvm-ir flag. That is not the issue but thank you.

Comment: Why do you believe that Rust uses those things (*invokes, landing pads and unwinds*) at all?

Comment: I did say it does. I expected it after reading [this](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/10/30/dont-panic/). If it doesn't use them then I'll accept an answer stating it like: Rust doesn't use them because of fact 1 2 and 3. :)

Comment: Also after watching [this](https://youtu.be/9TlR9hNZbck?t=1848)

Comment: Also what would be the use of `-Z no-landing-pads` if rust doesn't use it? (I'll stop with the "Also" now :) )